# Pandas not reading multiple Excel files from a path that uses "\"

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas' read excel function gives me back an error when I try to read multiple excel files in one go from a directory using "\" or backslashes.

pd.read_excel doesn't read a file that use "/RLTE/*.*". I have also tried "\RLTE\*.*" with no luck.

```py
#Set path to all Box Tracking DLs
path = r'\\es04cifs00\users$\USER\Winnt\System\Desktop\Box Tracking DLs'

RLTE_files = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path + "/RLTE/*.*")]

#Test proper filenames
print(RLTE_files)

#Test proper files: file contents should match filenames
for file in glob.glob(path + "\\RLTE\\*.*"):
    print(file)
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    print(df.head())
```

Error message is most often:

> xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'

Comment: The file it can't load - what happens if you try and open it in Excel?

Comment: I would check the encoding to make sure you're using the correct encoding to open the file.  I would also check the files once manually to ensure they are in fact excel files, if you haven't.  I get ".xls" files sometimes that are just delimited text files with incorrect extensions.  I don't know what encoding it is, but try adding encoding='utf-16le' to your read_excel statement.

Comment: Thank you, krewsayder. This download source frequently hands back files Excel claims to be corrupted. I believe it's originally .csv and improperly converted into .xls before being sent to us. Your solution seems to work